# CEFsharp crashes when opening multiple browser windows

Tags: cefsharp

Build no v57.

I have a WPF application in which we are using CEFsharp for displaying web page . The web page is a angular JS application.

When we try to open multiple instances of this web page or even in some situations one instance, the screen becomes blank. There is no HTML content in the view source.We are not using multiple tabs.

Is there an event handler we can use to handle this error on screen load and reload the screen ? Also for the multiple instances of the web page, should we use ChromiumWebBrowser x = new ChromiumWebbrowser(). is that the right practice or should we reuse the instance object above ?